# Implement onClick method in fragment using RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, android-recyclerview

In my app I have a Fragment that implements a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to list Firebase objects.

I would need to implement an onClick method to launch another fragment with detail info from the selected object.

I have searched on this question, but I haven´t found any answer that could be applied to my scenario.

This is the fragment code:

```
public class EnclaveFragment extends Fragment {

    private String enclave;
    private TextView mText;

    private RecyclerView mListaEnclaves;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Enclave, EnclavesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Enclave, EnclavesViewHolder>  (
                Enclave.class,
                R.layout.enclave_row,
                EnclavesViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase.orderByChild("Comunidad_enclave").equalTo(enclave)) {


            protected void populateViewHolder(EnclavesViewHolder viewHolder, Enclave model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setTitulo(model.getNombre_enclave());
                viewHolder.setDescripcion(model.getDescripcion_enclave());
                viewHolder.setImage(getActivity().getApplicationContext()  , model.getImagen_Enclave());
            }
        };

        mListaEnclaves.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    public static class EnclavesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public EnclavesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitulo(String titulo){
            TextView titulo_enclave = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.titulo_enclave);
            titulo_enclave.setText(titulo);
        }

        public void setDescripcion(String descripcion){
            TextView descripcion_enclave = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion_enclave);
            descripcion_enclave.setText(descripcion);
        }

        public void setImage(Context ctx, String imagen){
            ImageView imagen_enclave = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_enclave);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(imagen).into(imagen_enclave);
        }
    }

    public EnclaveFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            enclave = bundle.getString("KEY_DETAIL", "Madrid");
            Log.d("Enclave recibido",enclave);
        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enclave_connect, container, false);

        mListaEnclaves = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista_enclaves);
        mListaEnclaves.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mListaEnclaves.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Enclaves");
        mText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ccaatxt);
        mText.setText(enclave);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: @OlegBogdanov, I don´t see why do you find my question as duplicate. You are not helping me.

Comment: many people have already explained how to implement onClick within recycler's view adapter, how is your case unique here?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov, I am not an expert, I am learning, and the question you have considered is not about implementing onClick inside a fragment activity. May be you can help me further.

Comment: maybe you can explain exactly what you need and what you tried?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov, I need to click on one of the rows and open another fragment that should show more information about the selected object. I have tried including: mView.setOnClickListener(); inside public EnclavesViewHolder(View itemView) {--}

Comment: so which part is not clear to you? onClicks are answered on SO, how to run fragments are answered million times on SO, what is missing?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov, happy new year!, Hope next year you may be a better SO member and help  other SO members, I need help to solve my issue, if you don´t want to help me, don´t waste your time and my time. Thank you.

Comment: Likewise, hope next year you would appreciate reading the SO rules

Answer (score 0):

Register an onClick listener for the individual view(s) that, when clicked, should take some action, [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick).  The RecyclerView and its adapter have nothing to do with handling any events on any of its child item views.